# pglogical: list replication sets?

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

I looked at the docs of [pglogical](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/).

But I could not find a way to list all replication sets, which I created with `create_replication_set()`.

How to list all replication sets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the source](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/blob/REL2_x_STABLE/pglogical--2.2.2.sql#L82), that should be as simple as

```
SELECT * FROM pglogical.replication_set;
```

You need to be a superuser to select from that table.

Comment: Yes, it will list the set_id, set_nodeid, set_name, replicate_insert, replicate_update, replicate_delete and replicate_truncate for the ```replication_set```